# Steroids: supersonic.ui.drawers.init rejected: {}

Tags: navigation-drawer, steroids, appgyver

I'm new to Steroids and I want a navigation drawer automatically opened once initialized (AngularJS module for the drawer is named "profile-filter-drawer").

Here is my code:

```
angular
  .module('profile-list')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic) {

        var drawerOptions = {
            side: "left",
            width: 150
        }

        supersonic.ui.drawers.init("profile-filter-drawer#index", drawerOptions).then(function()
        {
            supersonic.ui.drawers.open("left");
        });

});
```

I keep getting this log in Steroids Connect and I dont understand why or how fix it.

```
supersonic.ui.drawers.init rejected: {}
```

Note: My navigation drawer is working (the AngularJS module is valid) if It is instantiated in structure.coffee but not from my AngularJS controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the drawer code in the `structure.coffee` then trying to instantiate another drawer of the same type would be rejected. I could be wrong on this, but the same happens when trying to push views that already exist on the stack.

This is a related [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/913) about pushing views onto the stack and them being rejected.

Comment: When the navigation drawer gets initialized in the controller I dont let the code in the structure.coffee so I dont think it could be the origin of the problem. Thanks for your time.